# How to use units package with rmarkdown for pdf document

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, units-of-measurement

I'm using the units package in an rmarkdown document for pdf output.
However, the units do not function either in-line code or as code chunks. Is it possible to use units with rmarkdown?

MWE for rmarkdown document in RStudio:

````
---
title: "Units in R Markdown"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(units)
```

```{r define units, include=FALSE}
len <- set_units(5, mm)
wid <- set_units(10, mm)
```


In-line code: The area of the rectangle is `r len * wid`.

```{r echo = FALSE}

paste("The area of the rectangle is ", len * wid)

```

I'm expecting to see: The area of the rectangle is `r len * wid`mm^2
````

Image of rmarkdown pdf document:
[image: Image of rmarkdown pdf document:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print(len * wid)` in regular R session will produce the same result. *units* are special objects and need special methods to be converted to a string.
Try this:

````
---
title: "Units in R Markdown"
date: "May 12, 2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(units)
```

```{r define units, include=FALSE}
len <- set_units(5, mm)
wid <- set_units(10, mm)
paste("The area of the rectangle is ", format(len * wid))
```


In-line code: The area of the rectangle is `r format(len * wid)`.

```{r echo = FALSE}

paste("The area of the rectangle is ", format(len * wid))

```

I'm expecting to see: The area of the rectangle is `r format(len * wid)`
````

[image]