# Less space between letters and units in rmarkdown (pdf and docx output)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, units-of-measurement

I cannot find any information about spacing between letters in R Markdown. All I found only were questions about vertical spacing. I basically have two issues:

1. In LaTeX I usually use the `siunitx` package to correctly typeset numbers and units. I can of course use this in R Markdown as well if I load the package with `\usepackage{siunitx}`. But this does not output to the docx format, only to pdf. That brings me to my other question...
2. So I tried using different spaces of LaTeX to display numbers and their units with at least less space, e.g. writing `40\,m^2` to display 40 m² (in LaTeX I would use `\SI{40}{\square\meter}`). However, apparently R Markdown does not handle the `\,` nor `\;` at all, not even in the pdf output.

**Question:** What is the correct way to add smaller spaces between letters in R Markdown? (irrespective of output format!) How do I replace the `\,` command?

And: Is there a way to handle units nicely using R Markdown? I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299748/how-to-use-units-package-with-rmarkdown-for-pdf-document) on the R `units` package, and I could live with it. That is, if I want to write hardcoded numbers like 40 m² I would have to use something like`` `r format(set_units(40, m2))`, ``right?.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding thin spaces using Unicode chars?  For example, this page http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html suggests that `"\u2009"` and `"\u200A"` should display as thin spaces.

When I try this with a PDF document (using `latex_engine: xelatex` to handle Unicode), this is what I see:

[image: screenshot]

It also appears to work with HTML and Word output.

Edited to add:

To be clear, this needs to go through R.  If you want it inline, use code like this:

```
This is standard spacing: 40 m², 
this is narrow `r knitr::asis_output("40\u2009m²")` spacing.
```

This produces this output in PDF:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your response! Strangely, using ``40\u2009m²`` outputs as ``402̆009m²`` in pdf and as 40 m² (with a normal space) in docx. I used ``xelatex`` as suggested.

Comment: I think you probably entered that directly into the text.  See the edit to the question.  If you did what I did, then I'd guess you're on Windows, and it's messing up the UTF-8 output

Comment: Useful list of unicodes char that completes these examples of the efficient solution provided by [user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330) is on [emptycharacter.com](http://emptycharacter.com/). Sadly, the specific 'medium mathematical space' doesn't work on MSWord output, and, as suggested above, you have to use `\u2009` in order to render a minispace in MSWord.